# How to use structs within multiple functions in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc

I want my program to ask the user to input the name of a car, the color of the car, and the type of car. I want to do this using a struct and only two functions. The first function takes in the info that the user inputs and the second function simply displays the information that was just put in. I have tried coding this but I have no idea how to use structs within two separate functions. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Automobiles {
   char  name_of_car[50];
   char  color_of_car[50];
   char  brand_of_car[50];
} auto;

void UserInput() {
    printf("What is the name of the car?\n");
    scanf(" %s", auto.name_of_car);
    printf("What is the color of the car?\n");
    scanf(" %s", auto.color_of_car);
    printf("What is the brand of the car?\n");
    scanf(" %s", auto.brand_of_car);
}

void DisplayOutput() {
    printf("%s", auto.name_of_car);
    printf("%s", auto.color_of_car);
    printf("%s", auto.brand_of_car);
}

int main() {
    UserInput();
    DisplayOutput();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way does your code fail?

Comment: I think the op is asking a more general question regarding passing structures to functions.

Comment: 'I have no idea how to use structs within two separate functions' - you already are, by defining a struct with scope that encompasses both functions.   If you want more flexibility, you need to define your requirements more clearly.

Comment: This does not even compile. `auto` is a keyword.

Comment: @Olaf: Good point, but depends on the C standard used to compile the code.

Comment: It must compile.  Surely, nobody would just post code that does not compile without saying so and including the compiler error messages.  That would be inconsiderate and insulting...

Comment: @Jens `auto` is a keyword in all versions of the C Standard

Comment: @Jens: Nonsense! 1) There is only **one** C standard: ISO9899. 2) There is only one _valid_ version of the standard: ISO9899:2011 (C11) 3) `auto` has been a keyword since pre-standard C (K&R-C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a structure to your functions as parameters, here is a possible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Automobile {
  char  name_of_car[50];
  char  color_of_car[50];
  char  brand_of_car[50];
};

void UserInput(struct Automobile *auto) {
  printf("What is the name of the car?\n");
  scanf(" %s", auto->name_of_car);
  printf("What is the color of the car?\n");
  scanf(" %s", auto->color_of_car);
  printf("What is the brand of the car?\n");
  scanf(" %s", auto->brand_of_car);
}

void DisplayOutput(struct Automobile *auto) {
  printf("%s", auto->name_of_car);
  printf("%s", auto->color_of_car);
  printf("%s", auto->brand_of_car);
}

int main() {

  // Declare an instance of an Automobile structure.
  struct Automobile auto;
  // Declare and initialize a pointer to an Automobile structure.
  struct Automobile *p_auto = &auto;

  // Pass the pointer to the functions.
  UserInput(p_auto);
  DisplayOutput(p_auto);

  return 0;
}
```

In this example, an instance of the `Automobile` structure is allocated as a local to the `main()` function. Then we declare a pointer, and initialize it so that it points to that local instance. Then we pass that pointer to the functions.

Your original code declared an instance of the `Automobile` structure as a global value and accessed it from within your functions. A possible implementation, but not always an appropriate one...

If you want to learn more, read up on "Pass by value" and "Pass by reference" topics at your local C knowledge provider.

Comment: should i change "auto.name_of_car" to "Automobile.name_of_car"?

Comment: @HelloWorld: No. `Automobile` is the name of the structure (a data type), `auto` is the name of the variable.

Comment: Okay because the program wont run on my IDE for some reason

Comment: If you have problems running the code, then paste your error message as part of your question and the community might be able to help you find and solve the problem.

Comment: the error i receive is "expected ';'... or ')' before 'auto'"(at lines 35 and 39) and "empty declaration with storage class specifier does not redeclare tag (line 29)" and "expected expression before 'auto'(line 31)"

Comment: @HelloWorld you are right; change all occurrences of `auto` to something else like `vehicle`